# Modbus RTU over TCP

Tags: apache-plc4x, plc4x

I'm trying to communicate with a Modbus slave using RTU over TCP, but it does not work. I don't get any exception. The program seems to wait for a response and no timeout exception is thrown.

When I change the Modbus slave to TCP only, it works fine. I can read the holding registers. Does PLC4X supports Modbus RTU over TCP? If yes, is there any example? If no, are you planning to implement it?

Comment: I'm no expert on PLC4X, but as far as I can see it does not even have support for Modbus RTU over serial

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, till now we only implemented Modbus TCP. However all the bits are in place to - probably quite quickly - implement other flavors. I guess nobody approached us with the requirement till now. Also would we need some hardware to test against. If you signed up on the projects mailing-list dev@plc4x.apache.org and asked your questions there, I am sure we'll be able to help you there.

Comment: Thank you very much Christofer

Comment: I am also looking for an example to communicate to device using RTU using plc4x library. I raised a query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821423/plc4x-library-modbus-serial-rtu-get-is-not-retrieving-data).
Could you please help here if plc4x support RTU/Serial communication to devices?

Comment: See comments on your other post